# surfing internet through openvpn

Tags: vpn, vps, openvpn

i have openvpn server
and the client are able connect to the server by ( openvpn Gui ver2.2beta5 )
but the clients can't surf the internet
what can i do to solve this problem??????

thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure your IP forwarding is enabled:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
echo "sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

NAT is configured right:

```
iptables -v -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o EXTERNAL_IF -s 10.10.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source SERVER_IP
```

And default gateway is set correctly:

```
ifconfig 10.10.0.1 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool 10.10.0.2 10.10.0.128
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "route-gateway 10.10.0.1"
```

Comment: You are making a lot of assumptions here, I think we might need a lot more detail from the OP.

Comment: how can i get this config